# Formulating a optimization with quadratic constraints

Tags: calculus, optimization

I have a problem where I want to minimize a linear function

$$\underset{w}{\text{minimize}} \ w_{1}x_{1} + w_{2}x_{2} + w_{3}x_{3} $$

Subject to the constraint

$$ w_{1}^2 + w_{2}^2 + w_{3}^2 = 1 $$

My understanding is that my constraint is quadratic. So one option would be to should formulate this as Quadratic Constrained Quadratic Program. However, I don't understand how to map by $w_{i}$, $x_{i}$ and the constraints into this formulation.

A second option I believe is to encode my constraint in a regularizer. e.g  $$ w_{1}^2 + w_{2}^2 + w_{3}^2 = 1 $$

Can be rewritten as:

$$\lambda(w^T J w - 1)$$

Where $J$ is simply the identity.

This would make my optimization:

$$\underset{w}{\text{minimize}} \ w^Tx + \lambda(w^T J w - 1) $$

But I again get stuck as this point as don't know how to solve for $w$. I think I need to take the derivative and set to zero but my calculus isn't good enough.

Which formulation is best and how do I proceed with the best one?

Answer (score 1):

By Cauchy–Schwarz inequality,
$$|w_{1}x_{1} + w_{2}x_{2} + w_{3}x_{3}|=|{\bf w} \cdot {\bf x}|\leq \|{\bf w}\|\|{\bf x}\|=\|{\bf x}\|,$$
that is $-\|{\bf x}\|\leq w_{1}x_{1} + w_{2}x_{2} + w_{3}x_{3}\leq \|{\bf x}\|$. 
Moroever, the value $-\|{\bf x}\|$ can be attained by taking ${\bf w}=-{\bf x}/\|{\bf x}|$. Hence the required minimum is just $-\|{\bf x}\|$.

Answer (score 0):

Think geometrically: the minimum of ${\bf w} \cdot {\bf x}$ on the unit sphere is at ${\bf w} = -{\bf x}/\|{\bf x}\|$.

Or were there other constraints as well?

Comment: w should be positive and none zero but I thought my unit norm constraint had these covered